# My Internet interferes with external device

Tags: ethernet

I am interfacing with some external hardware (can't disclose much details on hardware) and I am using Ethernet cable to talk to external hardware boards. I have windows 7 on my machine. In between the external hardware and my PC, I have a small ethernet hub that communicates with multiple circuit boards of my external hardware. 
Also, in order to get internet connection on my PC, I am using a USB2Ethernet adapter which provides me the internet connectivity.

The problem I am having is that whenever PC is connected to internet, certain test that I run on the external hardware do not work. If I dicsonnect the internet cable, then my external hardware works fine and I can do my testing.

I have disabled the USB2Ethernet through device manager and (I get no internet) and tried to run the test and my hardware doesnt work.

Has anyone encounter a problem like this and if so, what would be an ideal solution? Any help would be greately appreciated.

Please feel free to contact for any other information related to the problem if I haven't explained it well.

Comment: I need a clearification. You first said that if you are connected to the Internet, your test fails and if you are not connected, it works. Then you say that if you disable the USB-NIC by software, disconnecting from the Internet, the test still fails? There should be no logical difference between disabling the NIC and disconnecting the cable to it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment DoxyLover,
What I meant to say is that If my PC has the Internet connection, I am not able to communicate with external hardware.

I was trying to troubleshoot the issue by disabling the USB2Ethernet adapter Which did not help.

The only time I am able to communicate with external hardware is when I have internet cable (USB2Ethernet) disconnected.

If I have internet access or Ethernet cable is connected using USB2Ethernet adapter (even though USB2Ethernet is disabled), I am not able to communicate with the external hardware. 
Hope this clarifies my problem.